# React component test function call in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this component:

```
export const CityForm: FC = () => {
    const { state: widgetState } = useContext(WidgetContext);
    const { dispatch: geocodingDispatch } = useContext(GeocodingContext);

    const [city, setCity] = useState<string>('');
    const debouncedCity = useDebouncedValue<string>(city, 800);

    const fetchCallback = useCallback(() => {
        getLocationCoords(geocodingDispatch)(widgetState.appid, debouncedCity);
    }, [debouncedCity]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (debouncedCity && widgetState.appid) {
            fetchCallback();
        } else {
            clearLocationCoords(geocodingDispatch)();
        }
        return () => {
            clearLocationCoords(geocodingDispatch)();
        }
    }, [debouncedCity]);

    const handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setCity(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <Input
            data-testid={TEST_ID.CITY_FORM}
            type={'text'}
            value={city}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            placeholder={"Type your City's name..."}
        />
    );
};
```

I'm trying to write a test to check if `getLocationCoords` function will be called after user input.

this is the test:

```
    it('should call getLocationCoords action after 800 miliseconds', async () => {
        const dispatch = jest.fn(() => null);
        const testCity = 'city';
        const getLocationCoords = jest.fn(() => null);

        jest.spyOn(useDebouncedValueModule, 'useDebouncedValue')
            .mockImplementation((value) => value);

        const component = render(
            <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
                <WidgetContext.Provider value={{ state: { appid: 'test' } as IWidgetState, dispatch: dispatch }}>
                    <GeocodingContext.Provider value={{ state: {} as IGeocodingState, dispatch: dispatch }}>
                        <CityForm />
                    </GeocodingContext.Provider>
                </WidgetContext.Provider>
            </ThemeProvider >
        );

        const input = await component.findByTestId(TEST_ID.CITY_FORM);

        expect(input).toHaveValue('');

        await userEvent.type(input, testCity);

        expect(input).toHaveValue(testCity);

        expect(getLocationCoords).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

expect(getLocationCoords).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); `Received number of calls: 0`.

I cannot figure out why this happens. As the component works properly during manual testing.

Since the `useDebouncedValue` is mocked and returns the value instantaneously the `debouncedCity` within the component should update and trigger the `useEffect`

Comment: How does `getLocationCoords` get into the `CityForm`?

Comment: it is a function imported from another module. `import { clearLocationCoords, getLocationCoords } from "actions/geocoding";`

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a spy on `getLocationCoords` like so:

```
    it('should call getLocationCoords action with testCity as param after after input', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(useDebouncedValueModule, 'useDebouncedValue')
            .mockImplementation((value) => value);

        const getLocationCoordsSpy = jest.spyOn(geocodingActions, 'getLocationCoords');

        const component = render(
            <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
                <WidgetContext.Provider value={{ state: { appid: 'test' } as IWidgetState, dispatch: dispatch }}>
                    <GeocodingContext.Provider value={{ state: {} as IGeocodingState, dispatch }}>
                        <CityForm />
                    </GeocodingContext.Provider>
                </WidgetContext.Provider>
            </ThemeProvider >
        );

        const input = await component.findByTestId(TEST_ID.CITY_FORM);

        expect(input).toHaveValue('');

        act(() => {
            fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: testCity } });
        });

        expect(input).toHaveValue(testCity);

        expect(getLocationCoordsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```